# controll intigers from webserver on nodeMCU esp8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I would like to controll neopixel leds from over wifi with my nodeMCU but i dont know how to controll values over wifi, through a web interface would be perferable over url, but that also works.
usinf arduinoIDE for all code.

Comment: did you see the WebServer example of the ESP8266WiFi library?

Comment: yes i di but that shows just on and off when it detects a webpage loading and not seting a value in a forfum in a forum

Comment: and ESP8266WebServer library?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: there is a ESP8266WebServer library in the esp8266 Arduino package

Comment: ive taken a look at the web server and advanced web server examples but saw nothing, i can look at the direct .h file if thats what you mean?